# localstorage refreshing page save

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, local-storage

I have managed to save the data in local storage when I click on the two buttons I have. I wanna change the language on the page but when I refresh, it goes back to default? Why is that?

```
$(function(){
    $(".translate").click(function(e){

        languages = e.target.value;
        $(localStorage.setItem("Language", languages));
        localStorage.getItem(arrLanguage);
    });
});
```

Comment: It's because while you set the localStorage value when the button is clicked, you never read it back out again when the page loads

Answer (score 0):

Check if item exist in local storage, if it does use it, if not set it

```
$(function() {
  $(".translate").click(function(e) {
    if (typeof localStorage.getItem('Language') == 'string') {
      languages = localStorage.getItem('Language');
    } else {
      languages = e.target.value;
      $(localStorage.setItem("Language", languages));
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to actually use it

```
var lang, defaultLanguage = "en_UK";
$(function(){
  $(".translate").click(function(e){
    var newlanguage = e.target.value;
    lang = localStorage.getItem("Language");
    if (lang && newlanguage && lang != newlanguage) { 
      $(localStorage.setItem("Language", newLanguage);
      location.reload():
    }
  });
  lang = localStorage.getItem("Language") || defaultLanguage;
  doSomethingToShowThePageInThisLanguage()
});
```